# How to view the contents of a PBIX file

Tags: powerbi

https://www.fourmoo.com/2017/05/02/what-makes-up-a-power-bi-desktop-pbix-file/

> I followed the same procedure from the above link I am not able to view the content of a power bi report
> is there any way to view the content of a Pbix file

Comment: What doesn't it show when you do it? Can you add more detail to the question?

Answer (score 2):

That link is from 2017 -- It's similar but different.
Since [Enhanced Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-enhanced-dataset-metadata) it's now stored in `DataModel`

`Pbix` files are regular zip files. You can rename it to `.zip` or use `7zip`.
It's packaged similar to Excel `.xlsx` and ord `.docx`

[image]

## Export Using VS Code (or any editor)

1. Select 1 or more queries to copy. (It automatically brings required dependencies)
2. Paste into any editor

Copy Queries

[image]

Paste

## Using Tabular Editor

Run Tabular from within Power BI, and it'll setup the host and ports for you.
[image]

You're able to see your queries

[image]

[image]